# Hibernate alias to a simple boolean field

Tags: hibernate, alias, criteria, restrictions

I am struggling with the Hibernate Criteria API.

In class `Conversation` I have:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinTable(name = "Conversation_ConversationParticipants",
           joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ConversationID"), 
           inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ConversationParticipantID"))
private List<ConversationParticipant> participants;
```

And in class `ConversationParticipant` I have:

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "ParticipantID")
private User participant;

@Type(type = "true_false")
@Column(name = "Viewed")
private boolean viewed;
```

In my criteria I have

```
    Criteria criteria = super.createCriteria();
    criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
    criteria.createAlias("participants", "participants");  
    criteria.createAlias("participants.participant", "participant");
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("participant.id", user.getId()));

    return (List<Conversation>) criteria.list();
```

This all works ok and I can see all of the conversations for the given user. However, what I want is to see all of the conversations that the user has not viewed yet. To do so, I try to add:

```
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("participants.viewed", false));
```

However, this returns 0 conversations (if I put 'true' I get the same result and I have checked db and made sure that there are values with both true and false).  How can I achieve this?  What am I doing wrong?

The query that is run is:

```
from
    Conversations this_ 
inner join
    Conversation_ConversationParticipants participan4_ 
        on this_.id=participan4_.ConversationID 
inner join
    ConversationParticipants participan1_ 
        on participan4_.ConversationParticipantID=participan1_.id 
inner join
    Users participan2_ 
        on participan1_.ParticipantID=participan2_.id 
where
    participan1_.Viewed=? 
    and participan2_.id=?
```

DB Table:

```
 CREATE TABLE ConversationParticipants(ID BIGINT NOT NULL IDENTITY, Viewed CHAR(1), Type VARCHAR (255), ParticipantID BIGINT, PRIMARY KEY (ID));
```

Based on the answer below, I was able to make it work by using:

```
 criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("participants.viewed", Boolean.FALSE));
```

Comment: Side note: This looks hella complicated; `AS`,`WHERE` and `JOIN` clauses in SQL and Linq are *much* simpler.  I can see why you're straguling with it.

Comment: This should work. What is the generated SQL query, and the values bound to the prepared statement? I wonder if the true_false type is not what causes the trouble. Also, why aren't you using HQL for such a static query. Criteria is useful for dynamic queries, but it makes things more complex and less readable than they should be for static queries.

Comment: I have added the query that is being generated. As for not using HQL, well I am not sure how to write one, plus everything else is dynamic so I guess that it is not a real issue to use it criteria here as well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are trying to do is theoretically correct and should work. Nevertheless, I am thinking of some possible things that may prove to be wrong:

1. Make sure your getter and setter are properly used. Your code should look like:

   ```
   private boolean viewed;

   @Type(type = "true_false")
   @Column(name = "Viewed")
   public boolean isViewed() {
       return viewed;
   }

   public void setViewed(boolean viewed) {
       this.viewed = viewed;
   }
   ```
2. Make sure your DB field is a `BIT` (or the corresponding data type for boolean values on the DB you are using).
3. If neither *1* nor *2* work, I suggest removing the `@Type` annotation as it is not necessary, although it should do no harm.

**Edit:**

You are trying to map a `boolean` to a `char`. I do not really understand why you would use a `char(1)` instead of a `BIT`. Nevertheless, if you want to do so, work with a `String` in the model class.

Then, if your DB column holds *0* or *1*, use:

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("participants.viewed", "0"));
```

Or if your DB column holds *true/false*, use:

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("participants.viewed", "false"));
```

Comment: I have given above how I construct my table. The Viewed char (1) goes hand in hand with @Type annotation. If I put BIT for the column and remove the type it seems to work. However I would still like to keep char as the type (it is sortof a requirement), and I am a bit confused why it wouldnt work in this manner anyway (tnx for help)

Comment: Hi, tnx for the help. I have actually tried that before, your example got me thinking and eventually I tried to use Boolean.FALSE and it worked.

Comment: I edited your answer because the `"false"` will fail. use the datatype itself e.g. `false` or `0` instead.